# Are filed CVs ever going to be displayed to recruiters in alphabetical order?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

So Joel wants us to pay to have our CVs shown to recruiters. I am concerned that [Aaron Aaberg's](http://www.census-online.us/search/AABERG,AARON) CV is going to get more eyeballs than [Zulma Zylstra's](http://www.census-online.us/search/ZYLSTRA,ZULMA). Can Joel or Jeff give us an assurance that CVs won't ever be listed in Alphabetical Name order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results will be presented in location order most of the time, so those closest to the search location will appear first. Beyond that, we favor random order.

Comment: You're taking orders from him now?

Comment: Oh, _random_ order, not _random's_ order. Never mind.

Answer (score 2):

Sorted by rep of course :P (Or a mechanism to sort by rep :P)

Answer (score 2):

CVs will be sorted by votes first. Since they're all on the same level, they will then default to the next sorting method, randomly.

Because that's the way they like it.

Comment: Did not realise how close that accuracy was. Am definitely spending way too much time on Meta.

Answer (score 1):

It should be sorted by relevance to the employer's criteria. For example, if he searches for Java, the person best suited for Java according to the info he provided would be shown at the top.

Another idea could be sorting by last activity date (like in some dating sites, members who recently logged in are shown above those who didn't log in for a week).